# Button unclickable listView

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a listView with a button in each row. The problem is that I can click in my listView item and something happens, but my Button does not work, nothing happens. I've read some things about the solution, but none helped me.

Here's my **list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_branche_cours"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="English"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_trait"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" - "
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_designation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reading"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAjouterJalon"
    android:layout_width="58dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_add_jalon"
```

/>

And here's my customadapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private Context appContext;
private int layout;
private Cursor cr;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.layout = layout;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.cr = c;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);


   final Button ajouter = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bAjouterJalon);

    ajouter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent retour = new Intent(mContext,OngletJalonsNotes.class);
            mContext.startActivity(retour);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Thank you for the help.

@EDIT - my listview is unclickable now !!

Comment: Have you tried handling the button clicks on getView instead of doing it in bindView?

Comment: No, how could I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are making button focusable & focus on touch false so it will not detect your touch tab on your button, remove these two lines from your button tag in xml :

```
       android:focusable="false"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Example:

```
     <Button
       android:id="@+id/bAjouterJalon"
       android:layout_width="58dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/ic_action_add_jalon"
       />
```

*****************New changes*******************

CustomAdapter.class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
                private Context mContext;
                private Context appContext;
                private int layout;
                private Cursor cr;
                private final LayoutInflater inflater;

                public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
                    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
                    this.layout = layout;
                    this.mContext = context;
                    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    this.cr = c;
                }

                @Override
                public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                    return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
                }

                @Override
                public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
                    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);


                    final Button ajouter = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bAjouterJalon);

                    final LinearLayout root_view = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.item_root);

                    root_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                          // List item Click detected

                        }
                    });


                    ajouter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent retour = new Intent(mContext,OngletJalonsNotes.class);
                            mContext.startActivity(retour);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

List item xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_root"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_branche_cours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="English" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_trait"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text=" - " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_designation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="Reading" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bAjouterJalon"
            android:layout_width="58dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_add_jalon" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ty, it worked, but now my listView is unclickable, but my button works..

Comment: you want both should be clickable ?(list item &  button)

Comment: Yes, in each row i have some text and the button, and I want to click in both and do actions depending on what I clicked

Comment: yeah added changes in answer for different actions.

Comment: and the code I had for my listView.setOnItemClickListener must go to the empty method u gave me ?

Comment: yes, add your setOnItemClickListener their on root_view click listener.

Answer (score 0):

In your list_item xml put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants`"
 in the LinearLayout .